# Irobot create connection problem

Tags: ros, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a question about controling the icreate robot, after I run this command:
rosrun irobot_create_2_1 driver.py
The robot begins turning in the same place, and it shows the next message:
Bad data
I have restarted the robot several times, it does not work.
How can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12807/irobot-create-connection-problem/) by [andreapatri](https://answers.ros.org/users/1713/andreapatri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-01-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nouman Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/20072/nouman-tahir/) on 2014-11-05**:
i m trying to connect using bluetooth module and when i connect it i get same "bad data" with some more lines....plz help me

```
bad data
```

Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()

**Comment by [Nouman Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/20072/nouman-tahir/) on 2014-11-05**:
tryin to connect irobot using bam bluetooth module, but it returns "bad data" and "OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable" on driver.py....plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had to buy the USB cable, because my bundle came with a serial cable, so I got an adaptor, and it did not work. So I just got the USB, and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [andreapatri](https://answers.ros.org/users/1713/andreapatri/) with karma: 26 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-05-03**:
Please mark as answered :D